# How can I add a DB9 serial port to a laptop?

Tags: laptop, cable, console, serial-port, db9

I have a device I need a 9 pin serial port to configure.  How can I add this capability to my laptop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a USB Serial adapter. Something like [this](http://www.usbgear.com/computer_cable_details.cfm?sku=CHEAP-SERIAL&cats=199&catid=482%2C1303%2C199%2C461%2C106%2C1009%2C601).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively depending on the age of your laptop there are [PCMCIA to Serial adapters](http://www.usbgear.com/USB-SERIAL-ADAPTER-1x-Serial-PCMCIA.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get serial port cards that plug into an expresscard or PCMCIA slot.  (e.g. [this one](http://www.serial-cards.co.uk/productcategorydetail.aspx?CategoryID=55924))

Answer (score 0):

A USB to Serial adapter like this one:

You did not mention an OS, but this one will work for windows and it is the best one I have found for OS X.

[http://www.amazon.com/Keyspan-Speed-Serial-Adapter-USA-19HS/dp/B0000VYJRY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000VYJRY)

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using simple 1 port adapters. In my job I got lot o trouble using low quality one port USB Serial adapters.
We now use RocketPort 4 port RS232 to USB. It's much more reliable and faster then these single port solutions based on FTDI chips.